# What does it mean by the sub-clause '/quiet and /norestart command-line switches'?

Tags: php, command-line, installation, msvcrt, crt

Today, I come across the following sentence from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.requirements.php#install.windows.requirements) :

> The CRT installer supports the /quiet and /norestart command-line
>   switches, so you can script running it.

Someone please explain to me the meaning of the sub-clause **'/quiet and /norestart command-line switches'** from above sentence.

Also, explain to me the last part of the sentence i.e. **'so you can script running it'**.

Answer (score 0):

The `/quiet` switch means that the installer will run without creating any output at all.

The `/norestart` switch means that not to ask the user to restart the system after the installation is complete.

`so you can script running it` means you may automate the installation of PHP and the runtime libraries so no user intervention is required (or you may control it).